# How to run a php function in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I create an administrator window for my site with the ip-tracking database of ip2location lite so that I can see what ips is from which country. This page load extremely slow because i have to do more than 26 database requests every page load so i hope i can do this with 1 query maybe with mysql INNER JOIN.

```
php
function Dot2LongIP ($IPaddr) {
  $ips = explode(".", $IPaddr);
  return ($ips[3] + $ips[2] * 256 + $ips[1] * 256 * 256 + $ips[0] * 256 * 256 * 256);
}
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "username", 'password', "db_name");
if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysql->connect_error);
}
$mysql->set_charset ("utf8");

$result = $mysql->query("SELECT id,tid,ip,useragent,time,lang,page_s FROM access_logs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
    while($log = $result->fetch_row()){
     $ip = $log[2];
     get_ipinfo($ip);
    }
function get_ipinfo($ip){
        $s_ip = Dot2LongIP($ip);
        $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "username", 'password', "db_name");
        if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysql->connect_error);
        }
        $mysql->set_charset ("utf8");
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT `country_name`,`region_name`,`city_name`,`latitude`,`longitude` FROM `ip2location_db11` WHERE ? <= `ip_to` LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $s_ip);
        $stmt->execute();
}
```

```
sql
SELECT `country_name`,`region_name`,`city_name`,`latitude`,`longitude` 
FROM `ip2location_db11` 
WHERE Dot2LongIP($ip) <= `ip_to` 
LIMIT 1

SELECT id,tid,ip,useragent,time,lang,page_s 
FROM access_logs ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

it works but it is very slow.

Comment: Creating mysql connection object two times, So create only once and use it multiple times. Try create a singleton object to reduce some script execution time

Comment: Performing database queries inside a loop is considered a “No” in general, that is usually bad for performance (and probably especially so, if you work with a data set the size of the ip2location tables.) You should write one single query that _JOINs_ the data from these two tables together in one go. (If you are not familiar with JOINs, start reading up on them.)

Comment: @misorude I'm familiar with JOINs but i don't know how i run the function Dot2LongIP in it. Because the ip2location database not includes ips but a number which is calculated by the function Dot2LongIP.

Comment: You can not run PHP functions “in” database queries, at most you can run a PHP function _first_ to then have the result inserted into the query you want to execute in a second step. MySQL has several functions to work with IP addresses, go check if any of those can perform the task. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your database structure is not purposely built or maybe I should say that it requires refinement.

To enable the efficiency gains of a single JOIN query, you will need to create a new column to contain the value generated by [ip2long()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php).

I think you have a few hurdles after that, but I hope this nudge in the right direction will help to give you clarity.

Answer (score -1):

I have combined the SQL function INET_ATON and the JOIN and it works now my end result is `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM access_logs ORDER by id desc LIMIT 10) L INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 I ON INET_ATON(L.ip) between ip_from AND ip_to` This gives me the output i wanted it is only very slow it takes about 6 seconds for the query.